# How to access data in an array of objects in another file

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Basically, I'm working on an HTML page where I have to print out text that's stored in another .js file. The thing is, the text is stored in an object... in an array... in a function... in a variable. So there's lots of digging to be done, just to access ONE piece of data.

Here's the data (or something similar) in the accompanying .js file:

```
var TestDataSet= (function() {
  var reviews = [
    { Id: "abcd1234", 
      Title: "This Is Title Text", 
      Number: 5,
      Body: "text",
      CreateDate: new Date(2012,5,23,14,12,10,0),
      Owner: {
        Id: "Person1234", 
        Name: "James Smith", 
      }
    },
  ]
```

How would I make the browser return "abcd1234" from the First ID? How about "Person1234" from the nested ID?

The best I've got so far is this:

```
var data1 = new reviews;
console.log(data1.reviews[0].Id);
```

But this does nothing. I get a whole lot of "not defined" errors.

Comment: A more complete example would be necessary. Couple of remarks: 1) You cannot access `reviews` from outside the function, you'd explicitly export it. 2) `new reviews` does not make sense since `reviews` is an array in your example. You can only use `new` with (constructor) functions.

Comment: What's returned by the `TestDataSet function()`? The snippet is cut short.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you haven't posted your complete function.
However, I suggest to return the array value as in a getter function and use it if is safe for the rest of your script:

```
var TestDataSet= (function() {
var reviews = [
    { Id: "abcd1234", 
    Title: "This Is Title Text", 
    Number: 5, Body: "text",
    CreateDate: new Date(2012,5,23,14,12,10,0),
    Owner: {
    Id: "Person1234", 
    Name: "James Smith", 

    }
},];
return reviews;
```

});

Then you can access data using:

```
TestDataSet[0].Id
```